# Making global variables available to script parsed with perl_parse

Tags: c, perl, embedding, freeradius

I'm working on the rlm_perl module for the FreeRADIUS project. This module handles marshalling/unmarshalling of attribute value pairs to/from a perl interpreter. It allows AAA policies to be written in perl.

To simplify managing these policies, a user contributed a patch which creates a multidimensional hash table, that represents a multidimensional user specific configuration section.

For example

```
foo {
    bar {
        dink = 'donk'
    }
    baz = 'boink'
}
```

Would become

```
%RAD_PERLCONF = {
    foo => {
        bar => {
            dink = 'donk'
        }
    },
    baz => 'boink'
};
```

The issue is this needs to be available when the user specified perl script, which will be run by the interpreter, is loaded (it's currently only available to subroutines when they're called at runtime).

Allowing something like:

```
use constant FOO_DIR => $RAD_PERLCONF{'foo'};
```

To be specified outside of a subroutine in the body of the file.

The current C code looks like this:

```c
MEM(embed_c = talloc_zero_array(inst, char const *, 4));
memcpy(&embed, &embed_c, sizeof(embed));

# inst->module here means the path to the script to be parsed
embed_c[0] = NULL;
if (inst->perl_flags) {
    embed_c[1] = inst->perl_flags;
    embed_c[2] = inst->module;
    embed_c[3] = arg;
    argc = 4;
} else {
    embed_c[1] = inst->module;
    embed_c[2] = arg;
    argc = 3;
}

PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc, &embed, &envp);

if ((inst->perl = perl_alloc()) == NULL) {
    ERROR("rlm_perl: No memory for allocating new perl !");
    return -1;
}

perl_construct(inst->perl);

#ifdef USE_ITHREADS
PL_perl_destruct_level = 2;

{
    dTHXa(inst->perl);
}
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(inst->perl);
#endif

#if PERL_REVISION >= 5 && PERL_VERSION >=8
PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
#endif

exitstatus = perl_parse(inst->perl, xs_init, argc, embed, NULL);
if (exitstatus) return -1;
perl_run(inst->perl);
```

I'm providing it so that the various parts of the perl setup processes can be referenced rather than for comments or style or brokeness.

I'm guessing that between `perl_construct` and `perl_parse` I should be able to define other global variables, so that they're available in the scope of the file parsed. Can anyone give an example of doing that, or suggest another way of making configuration data from the module, available to the parsed perl script when it's parsed?

Sorry if this question is vague. I'm not that familiar with the concepts around embedding perl.